# Remove lines with a non-numeric field

Tags: text-processing

I have a file like this and I want to remove all lines whose second column contains non-numeric characters.

```
AC 14      68123822        68123928       
AC 16      34977639        34990886        
AG 2       162266065       162266181       
AC RS00192.1      415332  415454  
AD RS00228.1      20113   20230   
AC ST00228.1      22673   22791   
AC ME103_ID    190936293       190936410       
AD ME103_ID    190938851       190938969       
AH ME145_ID    147089817       147089932
```

And is there a way to count the number of removed lines? Thank you!

Comment: Please define _numeric_. Which of these are numeric: `1`, `1.1`, `-1`, `1e1`, `018`, `0x9`, `0x1p4`, `VIII`, `1,000,000`, `3,14159`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you meant decimal numbers. In that case, you can use `awk`:

```
awk '{ if ($2 == ($2+0)) print $0 }' my_file
```

This tries to add `0` to the second column to check if it is numeric (results in the same value), and only then prints the entire line i.e. `$0`.

This prints only the first three lines from the data you provided.

---

Thanks to @msp9011 for an even shorter, equivalent solution:

```
awk '$2 == ($2+0)' my_file
```

Comment: Whether that works for non-decimal numbers depends on the `awk` implementation and environment (for instance, for GNU `awk` where `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set, that will accept hexadecimals as well). Same for things like `infinity` or `nan`.

Comment: Oh, that's nice! I didn't know `awk` could handle hex numbers as well.

Comment: `awk '$2 == ($2+0)' my_file` will be same

Comment: @msp9011, so would `awk '$2==$2+0'` (and, though not with awk implementations, `awk '$2==+$2'`).

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {count=0};
       NF>1 && $2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+$/ {print;next};
       {count++};
       END { print "Removed " count " lines." }' input.txt 
AC 14      68123822        68123928
AC 16      34977639        34990886
AG 2       162266065       162266181
Removed 6 lines.
```

If decimal points are OK, use the following instead:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {count=0};
       NF>1 && $2 ~ /^[[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+)?$/ {print;next};
       {count++};
       END { print "Removed " count " lines." }' input.txt
```

The output for this version is the same given your sample input because there are no numeric-only second fields with decimal points.

BTW, if you don't want the removed lines count in your main output, you could print it to stderr instead of the default stdout.  Replace the END block with:

```
END { print "Removed " count " lines." > "/dev/stderr" }
```

Answer (score 2):

If by *numeric*, you mean sequences of one or more decimal digits, you could do (here using `-i` to update the file in-place):

```
perl -lani -e '
  BEGIN{$n = 0}
  if ($F[1] =~ /^\d+\z/) {print} else {$n++}
  END {print "$n line(s) were removed"}' your-file
```

You can adapt the `^\d+\z` regex if you want to include other kinds of numbers.

Comment: There's no need for the `BEGIN` block, since the variables get initialized to zero anyway. Also, the `\z` is superfluous here as the fields are guaranteed to never have the newline character since you invoked with `-l` option. So `/^\d+$/` will do.

Comment: @RakeshSharma without the BEGIN block, you'd get the wrong END message if no line were removed.

Comment: `END {print $n+0, " line(s) were removed"}`

Comment: @RakeshSharma, but doesn't help with legibility. If the aim is to make it shorter, you can always do `perl -lani -e'print if$F[1]=~/^\d+$/||!++$n}{print$n+0," lines deleted"' file`

Comment: @RakeshSharma, similarly, `$` in perl and pcre matches at the end of the subject or before a trailing newline character, while `\z` matches at the end of the subject, so is more correct. The day someone wants to switch to NUL-delimited records, it will not work properly. That behaviour of perl REs' is quite dangerous in general, I like to stress that `\z` is the proper way there to match the end of the subject.